# CKEditor select element: how to add key value pairs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

As the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.select) says, in order to add a select with some elements you need to add something like:

```
{
    id: 'my-element-id',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'My element',
    items: [ [ 'Value1' ], [ 'Value2'  ], [ 'Value3'  ], [ 'Value4' ] ]
},
```

but in this way Value1, Value2, etc... are both keys and values.

how to add a select differentiating keys and values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far my solution is:

```
{
    id: 'my-element-id',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'My Element Label',
    items: [ [ 'Label1', 'Value1' ], [ 'Label2', 'Value2'  ], [ 'Label3', 'Value3'  ], [ 'Label4', 'Value4' ] ]
},
```